# Divide a number up to 0 in PHP

Tags: php, loops, math, binary, logic

What i am trying to do is divide a number by 2 get the whole number and store the remainder in another variable which i did, but the number should stop dividing until the result gets to 0
Example:

75 / 2 = 37

37 / 2 = 18

.
.
.
.

1 / 2 = 0

This is what i have to far

```
$num = 75;

$n = (int) ($num / 2); //Get the whole number
$r = $num % 2; //Get the remainder 

echo $n . "<br>" . $r;
```

I know i have to use a loop but i am still new to this so i need help.

Comment: Use `while($num > 0){` after setting $num = 75. Add `$num = $n` after the echo, before the `}` of the loop. It's probably better to echo `"$n $r <br>"` than what you have right now (run some tests to see why).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try something like this:

```
<?php
$num = 75;
$divNum = 2;
while($num > 0){
$newNumber = (int) ($num / $divNum); //Get the whole number
$remainder = $num % $divNum; //Get the remainder 
$num = $newNumber;
echo $newNumber . " " . $remainder."<br>" ;
}
?>
```

Output Look like this :

```
37 1
18 1
9 0
4 1
2 0
1 0
0 1
```

Comment: As per my understanding, one update is that once the value become 1 then no need for the next loop so it needs to be `while($num > 1){` : https://3v4l.org/NDJI8

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie agree with you, but user mentioned this scenario in his question , that is the reason to have while($num > 0)

Comment: Optimization and more accurate for large integers: Use `intdiv($num,2)` instead of `(int) ($num / 2)`.